# pandas join with tables that has the same columns based on a single key

Tags: pandas, dataframe, join, merge, left-join

I have two dataframe:

```
df1 = K C1 C2 C3 ... Cn. D1. D2. D3
      k1 1 2 4.      7   1   2   3
      k2 3 5 6.      1   2   3   4
df2 = K C1 C2 C3 ... Cn  B1 P1
      k1 1 2 4       7   0   0
      k1 1 2 4       7   0   1
      k1 1 2 4       7   1   0
      k1 1 2 4       7   1   1
      k2 3 5 6       1   0   0
      k2 3 5 6       1   0   1
      k2 3 5 6       1   1   0
      k2 3 5 6       1   1   1
```

I want to join in order to get:

```
df_merged = 
          K C1 C2 C3 ... Cn  B1 P1  D1 D2 D3
          k1 1 2 4       7   0   0  1  2  3  
          k1 1 2 4       7   0   1  1  2  3  
          k1 1 2 4       7   1   0  1  2  3  
          k1 1 2 4       7   1   1  1  2  3  
          k2 3 5 6       1   0   0  2  3  4 
          k2 3 5 6       1   0   1  2  3  4
          k2 3 5 6       1   1   0  2  3  4
          k2 3 5 6       1   1   1  2  3  4
```

I dont want to do left join on the columns [K.... Cn] because it will be very heavy.
What is the best way to do so?

Comment: Why would a left merge be heavier than another solution?

Comment: @mozway how would you do it with left join? It didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, if we can find sub-arrays in the matrix, it could shrink the quantities of combination.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(np.meshgrid(['k1 1 2 4 7','k2 3 5 6 1'],[0,1],[0,1],['1 2 3', '2 3 4'])).T.reshape(-1,4), columns=['KC','B','P','D'])
df
###
```

[image]

```
front = pd.DataFrame(df['KC'].str.split(' ').values.tolist()).add_prefix('C_')
front
###
   C_0 C_1 C_2 C_3 C_4
0   k1   1   2   4   7
1   k1   1   2   4   7
2   k2   3   5   6   1
3   k2   3   5   6   1
4   k1   1   2   4   7
5   k1   1   2   4   7
6   k2   3   5   6   1
7   k2   3   5   6   1
8   k1   1   2   4   7
9   k1   1   2   4   7
10  k2   3   5   6   1
11  k2   3   5   6   1
12  k1   1   2   4   7
13  k1   1   2   4   7
14  k2   3   5   6   1
15  k2   3   5   6   1
```

```
rear = pd.DataFrame(df['D'].str.split(' ').values.tolist()).add_prefix('D_')
rear
###
   D_0 D_1 D_2
0    1   2   3
1    1   2   3
2    1   2   3
3    1   2   3
4    1   2   3
5    1   2   3
6    1   2   3
7    1   2   3
8    2   3   4
9    2   3   4
10   2   3   4
11   2   3   4
12   2   3   4
13   2   3   4
14   2   3   4
15   2   3   4
```

```
# output = front.join(df[['B','P']]).join(rear)
output = pd.concat([front,df[['B','P']],rear],axis=1)
output.rename(columns={'C_0':'K'},inplace=True)
output
###
     K C_1 C_2 C_3 C_4  B  P D_0 D_1 D_2
0   k1   1   2   4   7  0  0   1   2   3
1   k1   1   2   4   7  1  0   1   2   3
2   k2   3   5   6   1  0  0   1   2   3
3   k2   3   5   6   1  1  0   1   2   3
4   k1   1   2   4   7  0  1   1   2   3
5   k1   1   2   4   7  1  1   1   2   3
6   k2   3   5   6   1  0  1   1   2   3
7   k2   3   5   6   1  1  1   1   2   3
8   k1   1   2   4   7  0  0   2   3   4
9   k1   1   2   4   7  1  0   2   3   4
10  k2   3   5   6   1  0  0   2   3   4
11  k2   3   5   6   1  1  0   2   3   4
12  k1   1   2   4   7  0  1   2   3   4
13  k1   1   2   4   7  1  1   2   3   4
14  k2   3   5   6   1  0  1   2   3   4
15  k2   3   5   6   1  1  1   2   3   4
```